# MySQL INSERT - Using a for() loop with query & do non-set values insert as "" by default?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, for-loop

I have two arrays with anywhere from 1 to 5 set values. I want to insert these values into a table with two columns.

Here's my current query, given to me in another SO question:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (country, redirect) 
VALUES ('$country[1]', '$redirect[1]'), 
       ('$country[2]', '$redirect[2]'), 
       ('$country[3]', '$redirect[3]'),
       ('$country[4]', '$redirect[4]'),
       ('$country[5]', '$redirect[5]')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE redirect=VALUES(redirect)
```

I'm a little concerned however with what happens if some of these array values aren't set, as I believe the above assumes there's 5 sets of values (10 values in total), which definitely isn't certain. **If a value is null/0 does it automatically skip it?**

**Would something like this work better, would it be a lot more taxing on resources?**

```
for($i = 0, $size = $sizeof($country); $i <= size; $i++) {
$query = "INSERT INTO table_name (country, redirect) VALUES ('$country[$i]', '$redirect[$i]) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE redirect='$redirect[$i]'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
}
```

Questions highlighted in **bold** ;). Any answers would be very much appreciated :) :)!!

Comment: Are you sanitizing your input to prevent a SQL injection?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I didn't make that clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this:

```
$vals = array()
foreach($country as $key => $country_val) {
    if (empty($country_val) || empty($redirect[$key])) {
       continue;
    }
    $vals[] = "('" . mysql_real_escape_string($country_val) . "','" . mysql_real_escape_string($redirect[$key]) . "')";
}
$val_string = implode(',', $vals);

$sql = "INSERT INTO .... VALUES $val_string";
```

That'll built up the values section dynamically, skipping any that aren't set. Note, however, that there is a length limit to mysql query strings, set by the max_allowed_packet setting. If you're building a "huge" query, you'll have to split it into multiple smaller ones if it exceeds this limit.

Comment: Thanks, just what I'm looking for, I'll adapt this to my needs, as I've already got the first half of the code you've got constructed in a different manner, bottom line is to create an array with all the `VALUES` in, then implode each array value with a comma, then insert that as a single string?

Comment: yep. that'll handle the missing pairs option as well, since they'd never be added to this new temporary array in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking whether php will automatically skip inserting your values into the query if it is null or 0, the answer is no. Why dont you loop through the countries, if they have a matching redirect then include that portion of the insert statement.. something like this: (not tested, just showing an example). It's one query, all values. You can also incorporate some checking or default to null if they do not exist.

```
 $query = "INSERT INTO table_name (country, redirect) VALUES ";
 for($i = 0, $size = $sizeof($country); $i <= size; $i++) {
  if(array_key_exists($i, $country && array_key_exists($i, $redirect)
   if($i + 1 != $size){
     $query .= "('".$country[$i]."', '".$redirect[$i]).",";
   }  else $query .= "('".$country[$i]."', '".$redirect[$i].")";
  }
 }
 $query .= " ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE redirect=VALUES(redirect);"
 $result = mysql_query($query);
```